# Non-unique variable names in JS

Tags: javascript

Is it valid to use variable names again and again? For example:

```
function clicks() {
    var foo = document.getElementById("cat");
    foo.click();

    var foo = document.getElementById("dog");
    foo.click(); // Again! This works, but may be it is not valid?
}
```

Or I should use unique variable names, like below?

```
function clicks() {
    var foo1 = document.getElementById("cat");
    foo1.click();

    var foo2 = document.getElementById("dog");
    foo2.click();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you tighten up your question. What is the perceived problem you  are trying to solve? Why would you not use two variables for two different things--you're worried that somehow more variables are costly? What do you mean by "valid"--syntactically valid, or jshint-valid, or conceptually valid? In any case, if you do decide to "re-use" a variable, you don't need to declare it again--the second declaration will just be ignored.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with overwriting the value of a variable. Do note that it can make the behavior of your application more confusing, e.g., if someone reading through your code misses where you redeclare the variable. Note that after you've declared it once you can just do `foo = document.getElementById("dog");` instead of `var foo = document.getElementById("dog");`.

Comment: He's not talking about overwriting the value of a variable. He's talking about redeclaring it, which is something entirely different.

Comment: But there's no such thing as redeclaring a variable, since variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope anyway.

Comment: Why would it make the behavior more confusing?

Comment: @royhowie I say it could make it more confusing since someone could think #cat was being clicked again instead of #dog if they saw only the initial declaration and missed the overwrite.

Comment: @TAGraves but what does that have to do with `var foo = …` vs. `foo = …`?

Comment: @royhowie it doesn't have anything to do with that, but I didn't take the question to be about that either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is valid. This is because the interpreter "hoists" the variable declaration. That is, it moves the declaration to the top of the current function scope.

To the interpreter, your code "looks" like this:

```
function clicks () {
    var foo;

    foo = /* something */

    foo = /* something */
}
```

Now, if you don't want this behavior, you can use `let`, which stays at the current scope. For example:

```
function bar () {
    if (true) {
        let foo = 5
    }

    console.log(foo)    // not defined
    // you would need to declare foo again with `let foo = ...`
}
```

Comment: Note: `let` is new syntax and is not supported in all browsers in use.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, yes, you can use multiple variables with the same name but they all of them will share the same entity. It will be just one variable under that name.

But practically you should avoid that.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. They are not "multiple variables with the same name sharing the same entity", whatever that means. It is one variable, which appears in two `var` statements.

Answer (score -2):

You can't re instantiate a variable in js so the `var foo` twice should not even work:/

the solution is to use something like this

```
function clicks() {
    var foo = document.getElementById("cat");
    foo.click();

    //remove var in this line...
    foo = document.getElementById("dog");
    foo.click(); // Again! This works, but may be it is not valid?
}
```

Comment: It works fine.  The second declaration `var foo` is just ignored and it just becomes an assignment to `foo`.

Comment: And variables are not "instantiated"; they are declared.